# Find Resolution of the Monitors when using dual monitor in (IE & Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my Web application I need to adjust a grid width based on monitor resolution (1024×1024 and 2048×1280).

Here the user uses multiple monitors simultaneously. Whenever user drags from one monitor to another I need to change the grid width to the monitor width.

Code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    var Width = screen.availWidth;
    window.onresize = SetScreenSize;
});

function SetScreenSize() {        
    $("#tblContent").css("width", Width + "px");
}
```

Here the problem is when I drag browser window from primary monitor to secondary monitor, the secondary monitor showing same `screen.availWidth` (Resolution) of primary monitor.

Comment: Unfortenately browser is aware only of the dimensions of the primary monitor, there's no way to detect other monitor(s) reliably.

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, you're only setting the `Width` variable when the page is loaded - so therefore the width is only set on the first monitor the page is finished loading on. Instead you should query it each time the window is resized. Like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   window.onresize = SetScreenSize;

});
function SetScreenSize() {

    $("#tblContent").css("width", screen.availWidth + "px");

}
```

It should work